# Search a specific Play Store category

Tags: android, uri, google-play

I use this `URI` to search the **Play Store**, but the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#PerformingSearch) don't mention a way to search a specific category like, games, music, or books.

```
URI marketUri = Uri.parse("market://search?q= ");
```

The **Play Books** and **Play Music** apps both open the **Play Store** app to their correct categories, so if they can open to a specific catergory, then I think I can search one. Does anyone have some info on doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. Here's the current method I'm using to shop the **music** category.

```
public static void shopFor(Context context, String artistName) {
    String str = "https://market.android.com/search?q=%s&c=music&featured=MUSIC_STORE_SEARCH";
    Intent shopIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.format(str, Uri.encode(artistName))));
    shopIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shopIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    context.startActivity(shopIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a search at play.google.com in the books category and the URL looks like this:

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=android&c=books

try adding "&c=books" after your query and see what happens.

Comment: No dice. That's a solid suggestion though.